# Redirect out of salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I know force:navigateToURL will open up a site in a new window. Is there any way to navigate to a different site in the current window?

Answer (score 1):

To navigate to a different domain in the same window, simply use:

```
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
```

The force:navigateToURL method should be preferred, but there's nothing wrong with using window.location when you need to.

Comment: Do you need to specify SecureWindow.location, or is it interpreted that way automatically?

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld You use `window` just like normal; it is aliased to a special `SecureWindow` for a particular namespace. This all happens behind the scenes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax:

var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");

```
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": '\/https:google.com',
        "isredirect": true,
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
```